# reinstall keras. tensorflow in R on Win10

Tags: r, tensorflow, rstudio

I have r-keras and r-tension CPU version installed on Win10. It works good until i received a warning message of `Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`.
Besides, I hv Nvidia GeForce MX150.

When I tried to re-install tensor/keras GPU version by `library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "gpu")`

it shows `Error: Error 1 occurred installing packages into conda environment r-tensorflow`

Please advise how I can hv the GPU version installed. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you install tensorflow and cuda yourself. It's a bit fuss but you don't have to mess around with anaconda.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks. you mean uninstall present tensorflow on python, and re-install tensor and CUDA?

Comment: you have tensorflow installed in Python already? If so, make sure that your Python version supports this TF version. Also, make sure you've installed tensoflow-gpu rather just tensorflow. If you have cuda installed, you need to make sure that it is compatible with Python and TF versions and that cudnn version is compatible with your cuda version. In short, you need to make sure all the versions match